# Divide Sum by Count several times optimiziation

Tags: sql, sqlite

i divide several Times by the same count of a column... is there a way to optimize a query like:

```
SELECT 
  strftime('%W', [DatumEintrag]) Woche ,
  SUM([FOO]) / COUNT (DISTINCT [DatumEintrag]),
  SUM([BAR]) / COUNT (DISTINCT [DatumEintrag]),
  SUM([SOMETHING]) / COUNT (DISTINCT [DatumEintrag]),
  SUM([SOMETHINGELSE]) / COUNT (DISTINCT [DatumEintrag])
  Material.[ID],
  COUNT (DISTINCT [DatumEintrag]) as Tage,
FROM [MainData] JOIN [Material] ON [MainData].MID= [Material].ID
WHERE ([FILTER] = '0015') AND ([MID] IN (156500, 156504)) AND 
[VOODOO] = '' AND ...
```

Will the

```
Count(DISTINCT [DatumEintrag])
```

executed several Times?

Comment: Run the query with just the first two columns and with all the remaining columns.  Do you see a difference in performance?  I also assume you have a `GROUP BY` somewhere.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I guess this is teach someone to fish comment? But adding third column `SUM(BAR)` doesnt change the performance? so how you difference perfomance with  `SUM(BAR) / COUNT()`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . If `COUNT(DISTINCT)` multiple times makes a difference to a query, then you should see the difference running it once versus five times.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I mean would  `SELECT SUM(X)` have a different performance to `SELECT SUM(X), SUM(Y)`? because if that is the case you cant tell if the difference is performace is becasue the `SUM(Y)` or the `SUM(Y) / DISTINCT`

Comment: arent these parts of table stats; if you update those periodically, depending on how aggressive the ETL load is on specific table(s), should be fine.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza. . . Actually, `SUM()` is probably not noticeable.  `COUNT(DISTINCT)` does much more work than a mere `SUM()`or `COUNT()`.